# How to wirite this Model

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON like this. Because the Crew is different from others, I don't know how to write its model. like factory xxxx.fromJson  Thanks

```
[
    {
      "Employee": [
        "Employee A",
        "Employee B",
        "Employee C",
      ]
    },
    {
      "Equipment": [
        "Equipment 1",
        "Equipment 2",
        "Equipment 3",
      ]
    },
    {
      "Task": ["Task a", "Task b", "Task c"]
    },
    {
      "Crew": [
        {
          "crew_name": "Crew One",
          "employee": ["Employee3"],
          "equipment": ["Equipment2"]
        },
        {
          "crew_name": "Crew Two",
          "employee": ["Employee1", "Employee2"],
          "equipment": ["Equipment1"]
        },
      ],
    },
    
  ]
```

Comment: create another model for crew

Comment: Could you give me some sample code? Thanks.@Niteesh

Comment: yes sure, just one question, do you want the entire json to be mapped to a single model. Or for separate model for employee, equipment, tasks and crew.

Comment: Your words really inspired me. I can try it myself to build separate models. I write lots of JS code, So I always want to iterate the whole JSON String. Whether this thinking(Separate models) mean to depart the Json to several parts first, then iterate every model(employee, equipment, tasks, crew)? I don't have to map to a single model. Moreover, I will appreciate it If you could write a single model.  @Niteesh

Comment: Done I've shared, a model for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Crew {
    Crew({
        this.crewName,
        this.employee,
        this.equipment,
    });

    String crewName;
    List<String> employee;
    List<String> equipment;

    factory Crew.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Crew(
        crewName: json["crew_name"],
        employee: List<String>.from(json["employee"].map((x) => x)),
        equipment: List<String>.from(json["equipment"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "crew_name": crewName,
        "employee": List<dynamic>.from(employee.map((x) => x)),
        "equipment": List<dynamic>.from(equipment.map((x) => x)),
    };
}

class CrewList {
    CrewList({
        this.crew,
    });

    List<Crew> crew;

    factory CrewList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CrewList(
        crew: List<Crew>.from(json["Crew"].map((x) => Crew.fromMap(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "Crew": List<dynamic>.from(crew.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    };
}



CrewList crewListFromMap(String str) => CrewList.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String crewListToMap(CrewList data) => json.encode(data.toMap());



void main(){
  String str = "{\"Crew\":[{\"crew_name\":\"Crew One\",\"employee\":[\"Employee3\"],\"equipment\":[\"Equipment2\"]},{\"crew_name\":\"Crew Two\",\"employee\":[\"Employee1\",\"Employee2\"],\"equipment\":[\"Equipment1\"]}]}";
  
 CrewList crewList = crewListFromMap(str);
 
 print(crewListToMap(crewList));
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this website [Quicktype.](https://app.quicktype.io/)
Just copy and paste your json and get models on any language.

But remember this is quick and lazy way of  doing it. I'd recommend you read documentation to learn how to design models